# 100% width & height background-image not working

Tags: css, background-image

I want the background-image to cover the whole available space without getting squashed.
Actually I thought that's whats `background-size` is for, but I guess I am doing something wrong because its not working, please help me.

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.myDiv {
    color: white;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/V7KSb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make body and html 100% height and likewise for the div

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.myDiv {
    color: white;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    height:100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7KSb/5/

Updated: given `myDiv` some padding and used [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) to ensure it doesn't go bigger than 100%.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the background is on the div and the div isn't big enough. If you must have the background on the div, try something like this:

```
.myDiv, body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/V7KSb/3/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the div's height of 100% in all browsers you need to set both: `html`and `body` to 100% height, but also apply the following styles to the div that is supposed to take all the available height:

```
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.myDiv:before {
                position: absolute;
                background: url(../images/ig.png);
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
              }
```